# AddHandler on localhost (xampp)

Tags: php, .htaccess, xampp, localhost, addhandler

I just install the newest version of Xampp.
It was running PHP Version 5.4.7.

The problem I'm encounter is some of my client's website is build with 5.1 or 5.2 and some function are deprecated. So, I'm trying to change the php version on those particular folder with .htaccess file.

This is what I put in the .htaccess:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php52 .php .php5 .php4 .php3
```

However, when I look at the phpinfo(), it still shows that my version is 5.4.7. I tried to restart Apache and Xampp, it's still the same.

Is there any httpd.conf or php.ini setting/module that I need to turn on to allow "AddHandler"? Or something I need to install?

P.s: My Xampp is a fresh install and didn't change any default setting yet.

Comment: well, I'm only helping them doing some frontend style changes only. So, their server will still remain 5.2 (don't ask me why). But in order for me to style it, i need to set up a development server (which is xampp) to make my changes off-site. Also, I'm only suppose to touch the view files, not any controller or configuration file. That's why i want to downgrade my xampp to php 5.2.